# Why do all databases have a public schema in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I was just curious why all databases in PostgreSQL have a `public` schema that is accessible to all users. I know I can revoke privileges and grant them to one user but why is that not the default?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

There isn't much justification given, but see section [[5.9.6][1]](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATTERNS) in the manual. I think the following passage answers your question:

> If you do not create any schemas then all users access the public schema implicitly. This simulates the situation where schemas are not available at all. This setup is mainly recommended when there is only a single user or a few cooperating users in a database. This setup also allows smooth transition from the non-schema-aware world.

Answer (score 4):

The concept of public schema appeared in Postgresql version 7.3. It was necessary to support backward compatibility. Therefore, the public schema appears invisible everywhere. It is likely that the public schema is no longer needed for anything else and it can be eliminated.
https://severalnines.com/database-blog/postgresql-privileges-and-security-locking-down-public-schema

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be the SQL spec. But, this is fairly logical what would `create user` do otherwise, require you to explicitly say what schema the user had access too?

If your users don't have access to any single shared resource, why not just create a new DB for them? Unlike in MySQL, a new database is a new database, and not an alias for a new schema.

I just wanted to clarify this, it means that each database has its own `public.` schema.

Comment: I don't think it's due to the SQL spec: "there is no concept of a public schema in the SQL standard." [Postgres Manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/ddl-schemas.html)

Comment: @CarlG But it allows you to use the DB without knowledge of a schema, which is how other engines work (because they don't have schemas at all).

Comment: @ElliotCameron Oracle has schemas, it uses schemas synonymously with users; users get their own schema, schemas can also be shared. 

Microsoft SQL Server has schemas (as does Sybase), with the default called `dbo` equivalent to `public` in PostgreSQL where if you don't specify schema, it defaults to `dbo`.

IBM's DB2 has schemas as well.

MySQL has the synonym `schema`, interchangeable with `database` so not really a schema in the sense of the others mentioned.