# Why does postgres seem to have lax default permissions?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create a database and a user with limited privileges. The user should have access only to that database, nothing more.

In a blank slate Postgres 13 deployment using Docker, I connect with the user `postgres`, a superadmin, and run the following:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE db_foo;
CREATE USER usr_bar with NOINHERIT LOGIN password 'pwd1234';
```

That's just it. Nothing more than that. Then I connect to it with the newly created user, using `psql -h <pg_host> -U usr_bar -d <db_name>`.

Replacing `<pg_host>` with either `127.0.0.1` when running `psql` from the Docker host machine or with the docker container name when running `psql` from another docker container. Also replacing `<db_name>` with either `postgres` or `db_foo`; they both yield the same odd behavior.

**What I expected to happen** is that the login above (with `usr_bar` user) for any of the databases would fail due to lack of permission. Or that at least I wouldn't be able to make any changes, but I'm able to run, for instance, a `create table` command and it works. I would expect the user to not have any permissions by default, since no `GRANT` was performed.

**So my question is**: Why does this newly created user has so much permission by default? What am I doing wrong? If anyone can also suggest how to solve this, you're welcome; but I'd like to understand the reasoning behind it.

NOTE: For the docker image, I tried with two different ones, but had the same results. They are:

```
$ docker run --rm -ti -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root1337 --network some_net --name some-pg postgres:13
```

and

```
$ docker run --rm -ti -e POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=root1337 --network some_net --name some-pg bitnami/postgresql:13
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do all databases have a public schema in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134574/why-do-all-databases-have-a-public-schema-in-postgresql)

Comment: @Bergi thanks for pointing that. It helps to understand, but I wouldn't say it answers my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. There are two things that conspire to produce the behavior you see:

1. The default permissions for databases allow `CONNECT` and `TEMP` to `PUBLIC`, i.e., everyone.

   That may seem lax, but it is mitigated by the fact that the default `pg_hba.conf` does not allow remote connections at all, which is restrictive.

   In a way, the `CONNECT` permission on databases and `pg_hba.conf` rules overlap: they both restrict access of users to databases. I guess it was decided that being strict in one of them is good enough.
2. The default permissions on the `public` schema allow `CREATE` to `PUBLIC`.

   That is an unsafe default, and [the documentation recommends to `REVOKE` that privilege in databases](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PRIV).

   The reason why this is not changed is backward compatibility, which is highly priced in PostgreSQL.

Comment: I'll save any newcomer a google search and mention here that "_hba" refers to "Host-based access" in the PostgreSQL context.

Comment: @conny I thought it was "host based authentication".